# Installing Docker on Elementary OS Loki

Tags: software-installation

Recently installed Elementary OS over my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Have been having a bit of trouble getting docker installed. Not much information out there.

Tried googling, and found a few hits such as https://gist.github.com/ChrisTimperley/17d5bf0276672367e86081fa74db4353, but nothing i've tried worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the instructions at [Docker Store](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-ubuntu).

At the point where you add the dockerstore repository, you need to replace **$(lsb_release -cs)** with **xenial**.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
       $(lsb_release -cs) xenial \
       stable"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tobias' answer is correct but is slightly outdated. Here's what you need to do:

1. Find the base Ubuntu version using `> lsb_release -a -u`
2. Copy the `Codename` from the output
3. Replace **$(lsb_release -cs)** with the **Codename**

*Eg*: If codename is **bionic**

`sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"`

4. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace the Elementary OS version (loki, hera etc.) with the above **Codename**

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesnt have specific install help page for elementary os , since its based on ubuntu follow this https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and **Please use (lsb_release -ucs) instead of (lsb_release -cs)** while adding docker repository in elementary OS